# Calculus Improper Integral Convergence; Which is right: Limits or Areas?

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals, infinity

Could someone please explain to me the following doubt I have on improper integral: 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{ dx}$$
I still think that since integrals signify areas that this evaluates to 0 instead of DNE (Does not Exist).
I understand that limit notation solution for this improper integral returns DNE, but the areas from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ cancel.

Comment: Your expression isn't defined at zero
You should revert to the definition of the improper integral as a limit to understand why the integral from negative infinity approaching zero doesn't exist.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am referring to the fact that when graphed, $\frac{1}{x}$'s areas from $-\infty$ to 0 and from 0 to $\infty$ cancel.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I am starting to understand your point. No to your question. Maybe you could explain a bit more.

Comment: @HighEnergy But $\infty$ is not a real number. It's a concept. What you are talking about is the symmetry of the odd function, but that only gives you the Cauchy principal value.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Understood. You mean to say $-\infty$ + $\infty$ does not equal 0.

Comment: $-\infty +\infty$ cannot be defined. As you pointed out, in this case it 'appears' to equal zero (what you're really referring to here is called a principle value integral). However, consider $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac 1 n = \infty \,\,\,\,\, \text{ and } -\sum^\infty_{n=2} \frac{1}{n} = -\infty$$ but using these representations, it seems like $-\infty + \infty = 1$. On the other hand, $\mathbb R$ has infinite length and if we subtract out $(-\infty,0)$ we are still left with something of infinite length so $-\infty+\infty = \infty$.

Comment: @HighEnergy Even $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^2+1} \ \mathrm{ dx}$$ does not exist, and there isn't even a discontinuity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition is a common one.  It may be intuitive to say $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx+\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{x} dx=$$ $$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \left(\int_{a}^b \frac{1}{x} dx +\int_{-b}^{-a} \frac{1}{x} dx\right)=\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \left(\int_{a}^b \frac{1}{x} dx -\int_{a}^b \frac{1}{x} dx\right)=0$$  However, one could just as easily say for any real $c$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx=\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \left(\int_{a\cdot e^{-c}}^b \frac{1}{x} dx -\int_{a}^b \frac{1}{x} dx\right)$$ $$=c$$ or

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx=\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \left(\int_{a/b}^b \frac{1}{x} dx -\int_{a}^b \frac{1}{x} dx\right)$$ $$=+\infty$$ or

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} dx=\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \left(\int_{a}^b \frac{1}{x} dx -\int_{a}^{b/a} \frac{1}{x} dx\right)$$ $$=-\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

The limiting argument for the improper integral is clearly the way to go.

Note that $x=0$ is the only point of infinite discontinuity of the integrand $\frac{1}{x}$ in $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Thus, $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$

$=\displaystyle\lim_{\substack{\epsilon \to 0+ \\A \to -\infty }}\displaystyle\int_{A}^{0-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}\,dx
+\displaystyle\lim_{\substack{\delta \to 0+ \\ B\to \infty}}\displaystyle\int_{0+\delta}^{B}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ $\quad$ [provided each of the limit in the R.H.S. exists.]

$=\displaystyle\lim_{\substack{\epsilon \to 0+ \\A \to -\infty }}(\ln {\epsilon}-\ln {|A|})+\displaystyle\lim_{\substack{\delta \to 0+ \\B \to \infty }}(\ln {|B|}-\ln {\delta})$ $\quad$

Each of those limits do not exist. Hence the improper integral diverges.

If we put $\epsilon=\delta$ and take $\epsilon \to 0+$, then we see that

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx=\displaystyle\lim_{\substack{\epsilon \to 0+ \\ A\to -\infty \\B\to \infty}}(\ln {\epsilon}-\ln {|A|}+\ln {|B|}-\ln {\epsilon})=\displaystyle\lim_{\substack{ A\to -\infty \\B\to \infty}}\left(\ln {\left|\frac{B}{A}\right|}\right)$, which still doesn't exist.

However, if you take the simpler integral $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$ (which also diverges), you can see that in the special case when $\epsilon=\delta, \epsilon \to 0+$, the limit evaluates to $0$.

This is called the Cauchy principal value of the integral, which matches with your intuition of symmetry of areas of the odd function.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mean to ask why $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{x} + \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't equal zero; it simply follows since these integrals do not converge.

Consider $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x)$; as we approach infinity the areas always cancel out after the fixed period and the value of the integral at any point larger than zero never exceeds $\int_{0}^{\pi} sin(x) = 2$ but since the $lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{0}^{x}sin(t)dt = \int_{0}^{\infty}sin(t)dt$ doesn't converge that integral isn't defined.

So simply put, if you were to integrate with a newly invented operation like this:

$lim_{x \to 0^{-},0^{+} \gets x} \int_{-x_{0},x_{0}}^{x}\frac{1}{t} dt$ you will get zero, but by definition, these one sided limits do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you said make sense. It is a time to get more understanding of improper integration. By definition improper integral is the limit of proper integral. In this case, you have four integral.

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{ dx}$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{ dx}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{ dx}$$
$$\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{ dx}$$

None of them are DNE. Thus the sum is DNE by current textbook definition unless you make your own definition. Taking the following as example $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{ dx}$$

If you change definition to the following, the integral is zero. 
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{ dx} = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} (\int_{-1}^{t} \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{ dx} +\int_{t}^{1} \frac{1}{x}\mathrm{ dx})$$

So intuitively, the areas cancels. By we somehow need to abide to definition.

Comment: none of them are DNE? Actually, all are DNE. Infinity as an answer to an integral is still DNE