# Convergence/Divergence of a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Problem: Decide if the integral $$\iint_D \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dxdy$$
where $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}: x > 0, y > 0\}$ is convergent

This is an old exam question where calculators are not allowed. My attempt was to use standard polar coordinates substitution $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ and integrate $r$ from $0$ to $\infty$ and $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The integral I got after the substitution is as follows.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r}dr\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos\theta - sin\theta}{(\cos\theta + \sin\theta)^3}d\theta$$

I then thought that the integral over $\theta$ converges to a constant C and the integral for the radius diverges, and therefore the total integral diverges. Out of curiosity i computed the $\theta$ integral and it turns out the value is $0$. Now I am very unsure of my answer because my old integral in the $xy$ world turns out to be the following in the $r,\theta$ world.

$$0 \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r}dr$$

Now to my question. What is the value of this expression? Can I say that  the $r$ integral is divergent and therefore the expression is divergent, or is the expression above 0 and the  integral in the problem convergent?.

The solution to the problem divided the first quadrant into two parts with the $y=x$ line, and studied one of these parts with polar coordinates and came to the conclusion that the integral diverges in one of these parts which leads to the main integral diverging. In their case, they didn't get 0 from their $\theta$ integral because they took $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. In my case, I got that specific integral to $0$.

Is my solution fine, and what should the answer look like with my method, or in general?

Comment: Notice that the integrand is odd on the region so if a value could be assigned to the integral as part of a regularization, it would be $0$. However, your attempt at a proof suggests the integral actually diverges. Consider the integral in a similar situation $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\:dx$. It, too, is an odd function that looks like it should evaluate to $0$. But this integral diverges. How was it shown that one dimensional integral diverges? And can you adapt that proof to your integral?

Comment: I suggest to use $u=x+y, v=x-y$ change of variables.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a multidimensional improper Riemann integral with an unbounded integrand and/or infinite domain is not straightforward as in the one-dimensional case.

First, we require that $f$ be Riemann integrable over any compact $A \subset D$ which is also rectifiable (measure of boundary is $0$). We then can define the improper integral over $D$ by selecting any sequence $(A_n)$ of compact rectifiable sets which are nested in the sense that $A_n \subset \text{int}(A_{n+1})$ and which exhaust $D$, meaning $D = \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Defining $f^+ = \max (f,0)$ and $f^- = \max(-f,0)$ the improper integral is

$$\int_D f = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f^+ - \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{A_n} f^- ,$$

when both limits exist. In this way $|f| = f^+ + f^-$ must also have a convergent improper integral.  It can be shown that the improper integral is independent of the choice of $(A_n)$ provided the above conditions are met.

Note that convergence of the improper integral of $|f|$ to a finite value is equivalent to Lebesgue integrability.  Without this absolute integrability -- even if we get conditional convergence for a specific sequence $(A_n)$ -- there is no guarantee that we will get the same result for another sequence of sets.

In this case absolute integrability fails to hold, since we have

$$\int \int_D \left|\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\right| \, d(x,y)\geqslant \int_\delta^R \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{r|\cos \theta - \sin \theta|}{r^3|\cos \theta + \sin \theta|^3} r \, dr \, d\theta\\= \int_{\delta}^R \frac{dr}{r}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{|\cos \theta - \sin \theta|}{|\cos \theta + \sin \theta|^3} \, d\theta  = \frac{1}{2}(\log R - \log \delta)\underset{R\to +\infty, \delta \to 0}\longrightarrow +\infty$$

We can find finite values for the integral (using iterated integration) but they will depend on the specific sequence of exhausting sets and order of integration. For example, note that the integrand can be written as a partial derivative and we obtain

$$\int_{0}^{R_1}\left(\int_0^{R_2} \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \right)\, dx = \int_{0}^{R_1}\left(\int_0^{R_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{y}{(x+y)^2} \, dy \right)\, dx = \int_0^{R_1} \frac{R_2}{(R_2+x)^2} \, dx \\ = 1- \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1}$$

However,

$$\lim_{R_1 \to \infty} \lim_{R_2 \to \infty} \left(1- \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1} \right) = 0, \quad \lim_{R_2 \to \infty} \lim_{R_1 \to \infty} \left(1- \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1} \right) = 1$$

Following a different approach we have

$$\int_{0}^{R}\left(\int_0^{R} \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} \, dy \right)\, dx = \int_{0}^{R}\left(\int_0^{R} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{y}{(x+y)^2} \, dy \right)\, dx = \int_0^{R} \frac{R}{(R+x)^2} \, dx \\ = 1- \frac{R}{R + R} = \frac{1}{2},$$

and we get yet another value $\frac{1}{2}$ taking the limit as $R \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\iint_{D}\frac{x - y}{(x + y)^{3}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y & = \iint_{D}\left(\frac{1}{(x + y)^{2}} - \frac{2y}{(x + y)^{3}}\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by $u=x+y\in(0,\infty)$ and $v=x-y\in(-\infty,\infty)$

$$\iint_D \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{v}^\infty \frac{2v}{u^3}dudv=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{v}dv$$

which doesn't converge.

Refer also to the related

- [Calculus Improper Integral Convergence; Which is right: Limits or Areas?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1853493/505767)

Comment: I'm glad that you did it, because I was somehow busy, although I wanted to finish it, +1. In my opinion, an explicit and very beautiful separation of variables and getting rid of one integration.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks! Indeed it looks a very fine way.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^M\int_0^{2M}\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dxdy$$ is positive but
$$\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^{2M}\int_0^{M}\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dxdy$$ is negative. So, the given integral does not converge.